# Change background color of specific section

Tags: html, wordpress

I have an HTML home page and what I would like to change a section of a page to a different color, the issue i am facing is that i want the color to the entire page. Here is an example of what i want to achieve: [image]

The code I tried here doesn't seem to change the entire page background color for the `div` tag

```css
body {
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<h1>The background-color Property</h1>
<div style="background-color:lightblue">
  <p>The background color can be specified with a color name.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It does for me. The div is as tall as the P. If you make the div taller, the blue will be taller too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your question is not clear, sorry. There is no such thing as "the entire page background color for the div tag".

I can take a guess though, and assume you mean that the background area for the div should be as wide as the viewport, i.e. extend into the margin of the page. In that case, the solution is as follows.

```css
body {
  background-color: coral;
}

/* This could be done inline, but using a class will be more efficient if there
   are more of these divs on the screen */
div.highlight {
  background-color:lightblue;
  margin:0 -8px; padding:0 8px;
}
```

```html
<h1>The background-color Property</h1>
<div class="highlight">
  <p>The background color can be specified with a color name.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

that is very simple 
you can put your element in a section with a specific id like this:

```
 <section id='naturePart' >
  <h1>WWF</h1>
  <p>The World Wide Fund for Nature (WWF) is....</p>
</section>
```

and then write css for this section in one of external , inline or internal way like this.

external way :
create a file like style.css and link it in your html page

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
```

write this code in your style.css :

```
 #naturePart{
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
```

in inline way :

```
<section id='naturePart' style="background-color: lightblue">
  <h1>WWF</h1>
  <p>The World Wide Fund for Nature (WWF) is....</p>
</section>
```

pay attention that use must use one of this way and inline way has upper periority.
if you use html4 or latest version you can use div insted of section.

best regard